# creating extension for SPSS with python

Tags: python, spss

So I have discovered the python extension for SPSS, and everything works fine, I have created some scripts now and included them in the extensions map and it works fine. However, now I have created a couple of scripts that require arguments, I thought I could just follow the same method but I guess not.

```
def Run(args):
    import spss
    def testing_p(variables):
        all_variables = [spss.GetVariableName(i) for i in range(spss.GetVariableCount())]
        variable_nr = [all_variables.index(i) for i in variables]

        print all_variables
        print variable_nr
```

With the following .xml-file:

```
<Command xmlns="http://xml.spss.com/extension" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="testing_p" Language="Python">
</Command>
```

However, this keep throwing the error when calling testing_p(['my_var', 'my_var2']):

```
Warnings
This command should specify a valid subcommand at the beginning.
Execution of this command stops.
```

I cannot wrap my head around this because everything works fine when not put in the extensions map and only doing:

```
BEGIN PROGRAM.
import spss
def testing_p(variables):
   all_variables = [spss.GetVariableName(i) for i in range(spss.GetVariableCount())]
   variable_nr = [all_variables.index(i) for i in variables]

   print all_variables
   print variable_nr
END PROGRAM.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an extension, which can be writen in Python, R, or Java, you need to create a syntax specification containing the command name, any subcommands, and the arguments and argument types you want.  Here is a picture of the start of one (SPSSINC_TURF, which is installed with Statistics).
[image]

This will guide the Statistics parser in checking the user input.  It also then calls the Run function with a complicated structure containing the user input.  You can use the functions in the extensions module to map that to  your Python variables and do further validation.  Here is a picture of the start of the Run function for SPSSINC TURF.

[image]

Finally, if the syntax is valid, your Run function calls the worker function to do something useful, mapping all the parameters to the specified arguments by calling

processcmd(oobj, args, superturf, vardict=spssaux.VariableDict())
which was imported from extensions.py.

Look at the doc for extensions in the help system, and look at some of the extensions installed with Statistics for examples.

Finally, here is a slide from one of my presentations summarizing the flow from user input to results.

[image]

Comment: One other point: if you don't want to use all the syntax apparatus, you can use the SPSSINC PROGRAM extension command.  You give it the module/function name you want to run and the arguments using the Python command-line argv structure.  While this is much simpler, you don't get the validation and packaging of the full extension mechanism.  Run SPSSINC PROGRAM /HELP for details.